# How to submit a job, by using an uploaded jar in Apache Flink?

Tags: mapreduce, apache-flink, flink-streaming

I've already uploaded a jar (which was generated through a word count java program) to `Apache Flink` web console through an HTTP Post request via curl and the get jars api shows the uploaded jar.

When I try to submit a job using that jar, it throws me this error:

> Caused by: org.apache.flink.client.program.ProgramInvocationException:
>   JAR file does not exist
>   '/tmp/flink-web-8aa36f99-87fb-4fbc-b155-237fd833fc32/:949611ce-345a-4cd5-986b-8ff9b0700852_WordCount.jar'

This is how my POST request looks like:

```
http://localhost:8081/jars/:949611ce-345a-4cd5-986b-8ff9b0700852_WordCount.jar/run
```

I followed their official [docs](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.3/monitoring/rest_api.html#submitting-programs) for reference. Where am i going wrong? Any help could be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ensure that the jar file is located in your temp directory. There is a ':' in path, is it correct?

I study REST API recently and successfully submit my job with POST request

```
http://host:port/jars/29525e98-3ece-49c1-85d1-5301a5a38900_myjob.jar/run?allowNonRestoredState=false&entry-class=&parallelism=&program-args=&savepointPath=
```

Also you can submit job via Flink Dashboard and detect correct url through Chrome DevToos at Network tab (or something like this)

Comment: Thanks, I'll try this and get back to you. According to the doc which I've mentioned above in the question, says to add a `:` before the jar id.

Comment: I tried with your above request parameters and still throws me the error. I went on checked within the tmp/flink-web-8aa36f99-87fb-4fbc-b155-237fd833fc32/ directory, and the jar does exist.

Comment: Did you remove ':' from the path and error still occurred? Obviously ':jarid' in */jars/:jarid/run* is just a template for real case.

Comment: Yes I did, once I did that it throws another error: `Could not run the jar` and `Neither a 'Main-Class', nor a 'program-class' entry was found in the jar file`. But then I've specified the main class when I created the jar and it works perfectly when I run it via cli.

Comment: Now it finds jar and it seems like a problem with jar file. Check if META-INF/MANIFEST.MF file in jar and if it contains 'Main-Class' (which you probably should set within maven-shade-plugin). Does your jar submit successfully via Flink Dashboard? If it does, simply watch http requests been sent via browser DevTools

Comment: Sorry about the delay. Worked with the Flink dashboard but not via a post request.

Comment: Thanks. Monitoring the dev console when posting a job via flink dashboard and pasting that post request, did the trick.